# How do I get the number of distinct files in a directory in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I currently have this code which returns the total number of files but I don't want to count multiple files in this number count?

Lets say I have this:

```
01Red.txt
01Blue.txt
02Red.txt
05Red.txt
05Green.txt

Get-ChildItem -File *.txt -Path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\TestDirectory" | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

I want to return a total count of 3 based on 01,02,05 but with my code I get 5.

How can I get it to return 3 and ignore everything past the first 2 characters in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might suggest `Group-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0,2) }
```

Add `| Measure-Object` to count the number of groupings (this would be 3 in your example).

Answer (score 5):

```
Get-ChildItem -File *.txt -Path "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\TestDirectory" 
| select {$_.BaseName.Substring(0,2)} | Get-Unique -AsString | measure
```