# Returning number of files in a network path? (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get the distinct number of files in a network path but for some reason it is returning 1 more than there is.

Files:

```
20170612PA
20170612PB
20170611PA
20170611PB
```

Script:

```
$numberOfDistinctfiles = Get-ChildItem *.txt -Path $filePath |
    Select-Object { $_.BaseName.Substring(0,8) } |
    Get-Unique -AsString |
    Measure-Object |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Count }
```

This should return 2 but for some reason it is returning 3. I have tried deleting and placing the files in another network path and it still returns the same. Is there something wrong in my script?

```
$numberOfDistinctfiles = Get-ChildItem *.txt -Path $filePath |
    Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Substring(0,8) } |
    Measure-Object |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Count }
```

Comment: @wOxxOm , not sure why but I'm still getting 3. Thanks for tidying this up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of distinct files in a directory in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504720/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-distinct-files-in-a-directory-in-powershell)

Comment: Use `Group-Object` (like I answered in your other question).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I added code with your suggestion and it appears to work. Is this how said I should do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question...if it works correctly, use it. You can also create a test directory with filename patterns and test it.

Comment: `Get-Unique` requires a sorted list.  It wouldn't surprise me if you got strange results with it.  I agree with Bill, however, that `Group-Object` seems much closer to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

[Already answered in [How do I get the number of distinct files in a directory in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504720/). Reposting until this gets closed as a duplicate]

Use `Group-Object`. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring(0,8) }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $numberOfDistinctfiles =(Get-ChildItem  $filePath  -Filter "*.txt" -file | Select { $_.BaseName.Substring(0, [system.Math]::Min($_.BaseName.length, 8)) } -Unique).Count
```